# Animate subplots and create video

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, video, plot

I have two big lists of lists, that contain data to create plots of two vertically stacked `imshow()` subplots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

list1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ...]
list2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], ...]

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

ax1.imshow(list1_item[i], interpolation=None)
ax2.imshow(list2_item[i], interpolation=None)
```

I want to create plots for every index of the lists and create a video out of them. What is the best approach to do that?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your previous version was/is much much clearer. You need to add how you called `matplotlib.animation` with the output of `ax.imshow`.  And also import all libraries in your test code. But, one way or the other saving to file and reading again is still the recommended route.

Comment: Another approach, is to use a different way to animate. [This example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/examples/animation/dynamic_image.html) would also work fine if you have multiple subplots. Just use `im1 = ax.imshow(f(x, y), animated=True)` and a second `im2 = ax2.imshow(...`.

Comment: Since I don't feel save in using the animation, it's better not to show what I have done. I think there should be a better solution.

Comment: Your sentence *'I tried matplotlib.animation and got some results'* is absolutely hard to understand without the code. And without it, also the rest of the question is impossible to understand.

Comment: I think what I did is not the correct way to do it. Isn't it clear what I need?

Comment: Is my answer to your other question what you're after? If not, please provide more information. The term "create a video" and "list of lists" can be interpreted in many ways.

Comment: I think it's exactly what I want, it's just not working correctly. :-(